# Escaping a character in regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am wanting to replace a certain character '@' followed by text (e.g @patrick). I'm looking to escape the '@' and just having the 'patrick' with the use of a regex expression

```
charFinder = re.compile("(\@\w+)")
content = charFinder.sub(r"<a href='/users/\1'>\1</a>",content)
return content
```

So far I have this and its returning

```
'"&lt;p&gt;Hello World <a href='/users/@Patrick'>@Patrick</a>&lt;/p&gt;"
```

When really i want it to return

```
"&lt;p&gt;Hello World <a href='/users/Patrick'>@Patrick</a>&lt;/p&gt;"
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Add the original string too

Comment: please explain further sorry im new to regex and python

Comment: Sorry i just made an edit please look again !

Comment: Can you add the original contents of `content`?

Answer (score 2):

Move the @ outside of the capturing group and then add it in the one location where you need it in the template.

```
charFinder = re.compile("\@(\w+)")
content = charFinder.sub(r"<a href='/users/\1'>@\1</a>",content)
```

This still uses the `@` to make the match, but doesn't put it in the group. You then add it later. For example:

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: char_finder = re.compile("\@(\w+)")
In [3]: content = "&lt;p&gt;Hello World @Patrick&lt;/p&gt;"
In [4]: new_content = char_finder.sub(r"<a href='/users/\1'>@\1</a>",content)
In [5]: new_content
Out[5]: "&lt;p&gt;Hello World <a href='/users/Patrick'>@Patrick</a>&lt;/p&gt;"
```

This appears to be doing exactly what you want it to based on the above question.

Comment: please have a look at my edit and what i need to this is not returning &lt;p&gt;Hello World <a href='/users/Bobolooba'>@Bobolooba</a>&lt;/p&gt;

Comment: @NubmcNub, I'm not so sure. Based on what you posted above, I think what I've shared would definitely fix it. One of us must be making a mistake somewhere! Can you post the code as you're trying to run it?

Comment: "&lt;p&gt;Hello World <a href='/users/Patrick'>@Patrick</a>&lt;/p&gt;" - in ' users/@Patrick' I want 'users/Patrick'. Thanks bro !

Comment: "&lt;p&gt;Hello World <a href='/users/Patrick'>@Patrick</a>&lt;/p&gt;" - in ' users/@Patrick' I want 'users/Patrick'. Thanks bro ! –

Comment: @NubmcNub, I still think my code is producing the desired result. Please see the example I've added above.

Comment: Works for me: I tried this out and got:"&lt;p&gt;Hello World <a href='/users/Patrick'>@Patrick</a>&lt;/p&gt;"